# Iterating over data in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am processing a queryset in a view to get a summary of data and need to be able to iterate over the resultant dataset in my template. I did this OK with a key and single value by building a dictionary and then using .items to work over key value pairs using:

```
{% for id,total in list_summary.items %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}" >
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{total}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem I have is that I need more than just a key and value. I need multiple values. I tried building a dictionary using a dictionary as the value but in the template I can't get to the values in the dictionary.

What is the appropriate datastructure to build to make this work? I thought of a temporary model or making a custom template tag to access the sub dictionary values but I think there must be a better way to process queryset data prior to feeding it to a view.

My view code is here:

```
lists=lists.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
list_summary={}
# make a dictionary that we wil iterate over in template. The dictionary has the total spend for each deal 
for list in lists:
    id       = list.id
    name     = list.deal_name
    price    = list.normal_price
    quantity = list.quantity
    total    = price * quantity
    try:
        list_item=list_summary[id]
        old_total=list_item['total']
        list_summary[id]={'name':name, 'total':old_total + total}
    except:
        list_summary[id]={'name':name, 'total':total}
context = {
           'list_summary':list_summary,
        }
return render_to_response("lists.html", context)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Have you tried [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) yet?

Comment: I suspect aggregation would do it if I could work out how to multiply sale value with quantity and then add it to query set that has distinct set of deal IDs with annotated total. I just can't see how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried building a dictionary using a dictionary as the value but in
>   the template I can't get to the values in the dictionary.

Why not? The values are also key/value pairs..

```
{% for list_id, dict in list_summary.items %}
    list_id: {{ list_id }}
    {% for k, v in dict.items %}
        key: {{ k }} <!-- name, total -->
        value: {{ v }} 
    {% endfor }
{% endfor %}


{% for list_id, value in list_summary.items %}
    list_id: {{ list_id }}
    Name: {{ value.name }}
    Value: {{ value.value }
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did the job, it was just a bit confusing to iterate over somehting I just wanted 2 values from. I am still not sure it's the best way to do it, surely there is a better way of constructing the data so I can iterate a flat object list rather than having to nest for loops.

Comment: Also I had to use the total value as the key and the deal name as they value, it's just weird!

Comment: If you want to access specific attributes or items in a template, you can use dot notation and django will try all kinds of lookups to get you the value you want. `{{ dict.name }}` should get you the value you need